# Enterprise Architect creating association between two classes in different packages

Tags: class, package, enterprise-architect

I have organize classes in multiple packages to handle large number of classes. How do I establish relationship between classes that are in 2 different package?

Answer (score 0):

Open any class diagram from Project Browser.

Drag the classes from different packages from Project Browser to the diagram. Select "Paste element to the diagram: as simple link"

Connect the classes with any relationship.

The relationship is kept in the class type so putting the classes into another diagrams will automatically draw relevant relationships